# Unusual characters not loaded in Nginx Drupal Boost static cache

Tags: nginx, cache, drupal-6, boost

(Setup: Drupal 6.20, Boost 1.18, Nginx 0.7.67)

When the URL of the boosted node contain character `→` or `中国新闻网新闻中心`, the node is correctly cached in the cache directory, and correctly reflecting the URL.

But when accessing the node, the uncached node loaded instead.

Below is the Nginx rules I use:

```
server {
    server_name *.com *.net *.org;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/$host;
        index  index.php;
        set $boost "";
        set $boost_query "_";
        if ( $request_method = GET ) {
          set $boost G;
        }
        if ($http_cookie !~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
          set $boost "${boost}D";
        }
        if ($query_string = "") {
          set $boost "${boost}Q";
        }  
        if ( -f $document_root/cache/normal/$host$request_uri$boost_query.html ) {
          set $boost "${boost}F";
        }
        if ($boost = GDQF){
          rewrite ^.*$ /cache/normal/$host/$request_uri$boost_query.html break;
        } 
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
          break;
        }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$host$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `charset utf-8;` under `http {` and under `server {`. Both of them not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $uri instead of $request_uri in your ifs.  $request_uri is unprocessed, so % encoded entities are still encoded.  $uri has been decoded, which may be what you need.